# Run small mail server using a second domain instead of dynamic ip hostname service

Tags: email, domain, mail-server, dynamic-ip, spf

How do I use a second domain instead of freely registered hostname, assigned to a dynamic ip address, in place of email address domain?

something like contact@exemplo.com.br instead of contact@suportese.no-ip.org .

If I understand the logic, I should add, in domain registrar web control painel, a MX entry pointing to MX record on hostname (dynip) service, MX server = hostname (dynip), and a DNS TXT entry "v=spf1 mx include:suportese.no-ip.org -all".

For the configuration of the hostname service, in case of noip, should have a spf record, so it'd be like "v=spf1 a:exemplo.com.br -all". And a MX record, which is exactly same as hostname.

Is that how it goes ?

Consider this scenario:

- W2k8 R2
- hMailServer 5.6.4 - Build 2283
- Domain Registrar - registro.br - "exemplo.com.br" (there is also DNS service)
- Dynamic IP - NoIp Free Hostname "suportese.no-ip.org"

Before hand, don't waste your time saying it's bad idea to maintain a mail server o dynamic ip because I've already read all of that about rejection of dynamic ip and loss of email.

Thank you for your time

Regard

Answer (score 0):

Your MX record will point to a FQDN (A record) not to the IP itself. Likewise, if you setup an SPF record that is adding your MX record as a good sender for your mail, it is not using your IP either (as your example shows you are adding the MX record to the list of sender).

So the only piece left is maintaining your A record to point to the correct IP, which if it is dynamic means you will be changing it regularly.

Comment: Yes, MX record is a fqdn 'suportese.no-ip.org' set in hosts dynamic ip service. Which is the same as Hostname itself. Is that right ? For the SPF record of domain registrar (this part I didn't get well), it should lose the include:suportese.no-ip.org part ? For last, it ruins everything, because I can't use a 'domain cname hostname' entry ?

Comment: You got it. The SPF record (in my opinion) is a mostly useless record, but since some receiving sites do use it to verify the sending server is allowed to send mail for the domain you are correct in wanting it in place. In a nutshell the SPF record means - these servers are allowed to send mail for this domain. So in your case yes I would start with "v=spf1 mx ~all" (naturally with the SPF record being for your domain).

Comment: One more recommendation - as the MX and SPF are working on the two opposite sides of the email pathway (MX is for inbound, SPF is for outbound) you can test each direction independently so that you can troubleshoot any issues that may arise. I find inbound easier to test (as you can manually test SMTP connections) whereas finding an outbound failure is harder.